# Executing a JavaScript(?) script on a website through R in order to download the file

Tags: javascript, r, api, get, httr

The US Treasury posts results of its auctions on the website linked below:
https://www.treasurydirect.gov/auctions/auction-query/

What I would like to do is to select all the columns from the "Show / Hide Columns" button, show 1000 rows in the "Show rows" from the list box in the bottom right corner and download a CSV file through the script that runs after clicking "CSV" button. I will write a for loop in order to perform the task 10 times so I can download all the data at once every time.

I read on the Internet that GET() and POST() functions from the 'httr' package may be beneficial to perform this task, but I have completely no idea where to start and any guidance will be appreciated.
[Query result in Chrome Developer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjeGl.png)

My experience in web-related activities in R is limited to the 'rvest' package and web scrapping html data from websites. I tried adding arguments into POST() function, but it resulted with nothing.

Comment: `rvest` cannot interact with javascript. Either you need to reverse engineer the site to figure out what the javascript it doing and do it manually yourself, or use a package like RSelenium that can run javascript and interact with webpages. The approach you use is very specific to each website you need to scrape.

Answer (score 2):

With the API link that I found in the network section in the developer tools. Scraping the first 1000 rows. Inspect the embedded URL and loop to gather all observations.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(httr2)

"https://www.treasurydirect.gov/TA_WS/securities/jqsearch?format=json&callback=jQuery360005083887372902929_1675098529599&filterscount=0&groupscount=0&pagenum=0&pagesize=1000&recordstartindex=0&recordendindex=1000" %>% 
  request() %>%  
  req_perform() %>% 
  resp_body_json(simplifyVector = TRUE) %>% 
  pluck("securityList") %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  type_convert()
```

**Output:**

```
# A tibble: 1,000 × 118
   cusip    issueDate           secur…¹ secur…² maturityDate        inter…³ refCp…⁴ refCp…⁵ announcementDate    auctionDate         aucti…⁶
   <chr>    <dttm>              <chr>   <chr>   <dttm>                <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <dttm>              <dttm>                <dbl>
 1 912796Y… 2023-02-02 00:00:00 Bill    13-Week 2023-05-04 00:00:00   NA         NA      NA 2023-01-26 00:00:00 2023-01-30 00:00:00    2023
 2 912796Y… 2023-02-02 00:00:00 Bill    26-Week 2023-08-03 00:00:00   NA         NA      NA 2023-01-26 00:00:00 2023-01-30 00:00:00    2023
 3 912796Y… 2023-01-31 00:00:00 Bill    4-Week  2023-02-28 00:00:00   NA         NA      NA 2023-01-24 00:00:00 2023-01-26 00:00:00    2023
 4 912796Z… 2023-01-31 00:00:00 Bill    8-Week  2023-03-28 00:00:00   NA         NA      NA 2023-01-24 00:00:00 2023-01-26 00:00:00    2023
 5 91282CG… 2023-01-31 00:00:00 Note    7-Year  2030-01-31 00:00:00    3.5       NA      NA 2023-01-19 00:00:00 2023-01-26 00:00:00    2023
 6 912797F… 2023-01-31 00:00:00 Bill    17-Week 2023-05-30 00:00:00   NA         NA      NA 2023-01-24 00:00:00 2023-01-25 00:00:00    2023
 7 91282CG… 2023-01-31 00:00:00 Note    2-Year  2025-01-31 00:00:00   NA         NA      NA 2023-01-19 00:00:00 2023-01-25 00:00:00    2023
 8 91282CG… 2023-01-31 00:00:00 Note    5-Year  2028-01-31 00:00:00    3.5       NA      NA 2023-01-19 00:00:00 2023-01-25 00:00:00    2023
 9 91282CG… 2023-01-31 00:00:00 Note    2-Year  2025-01-31 00:00:00    4.12      NA      NA 2023-01-19 00:00:00 2023-01-24 00:00:00    2023
10 912796Z… 2023-01-26 00:00:00 Bill    52-Week 2024-01-25 00:00:00   NA         NA      NA 2023-01-19 00:00:00 2023-01-24 00:00:00    2023
# … with 990 more rows, 107 more variables: datedDate <dttm>, accruedInterestPer1000 <dbl>, accruedInterestPer100 <dbl>,
#   adjustedAccruedInterestPer1000 <dbl>, adjustedPrice <dbl>, allocationPercentage <dbl>, allocationPercentageDecimals <dbl>,
#   announcedCusip <chr>, auctionFormat <chr>, averageMedianDiscountRate <dbl>, averageMedianInvestmentRate <lgl>,
#   averageMedianPrice <lgl>, averageMedianDiscountMargin <dbl>, averageMedianYield <dbl>, backDated <chr>, backDatedDate <dttm>,
#   bidToCoverRatio <dbl>, callDate <lgl>, callable <chr>, calledDate <lgl>, cashManagementBillCMB <chr>, closingTimeCompetitive <time>,
#   closingTimeNoncompetitive <time>, competitiveAccepted <dbl>, competitiveBidDecimals <dbl>, competitiveTendered <dbl>,
#   competitiveTendersAccepted <chr>, corpusCusip <chr>, cpiBaseReferencePeriod <chr>, currentlyOutstanding <dbl>, …
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows, and `colnames()` to see all variable names
```